# MySQLdb, Python raw query and customized ORDER BY

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am trying to do the following :

```
query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY %s %s"
parameters = ['avg', 'DESC']
```

But the parameters are not mapped correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 'avg' 'DESC'
```

Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY avg DESC
```

Do you know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this:

```
"SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY %s %s" % ('avg', 'DESC')
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Although depending on where those values originate, you could have an injection risk

Comment: For this parameters I can prevent the injection, but not for the other used before. Using concatenation, I should be able to do it before.

Comment: That's another story (programmatic problem) and the question was technical. But I agree with you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use parameters to dynamically specify field names.  They specify values only.